# How to return fitting equation in excel

Tags: excel

In excel, I am doing a simple linear regression of two vector X and Y. When I plot X vs Y and fit with linear equation and the result y = kx + b can be shown in the figure. I need to use k and b for my further calculation. I am wondering if there is any equation that can direct return the value of k and b in excel.

Many thanks in advance for he help!

Comment: See:  http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/chart_trendline_formulas/

Comment: You might also be able to use LINEST.  Unless you are using an older version of Excel (prior to 2007, if memory serves), you should get the same results.

Comment: Great！This also works!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `x` values are in A2:A10 and `y` in B2:B10, your slope (`k`) with:

```
=LINEST(B2:B10,A2:A10)
```

and the intercept (`b`) with:

```
=INTERCEPT(B2:B10,A2:A10)
```